# Convert the Given String to Minutes

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column with the time in String format.
The format is
`PT5H1M15S which is equivalent to 5 Hour 1 Minute and 15 Second(Pacific Time)`. I am new to R and need to convert this to Minutes. Any help here is appreciated. Thanks.

My expected answer is 301.25 Minutes

Comment: We can try `library(lubridate);minutes(hms(str1))`

Comment: @G5W Yea that's the expected answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(hms(str1))/60
#[1] 301.25
```

Or

```
as.numeric(hms(str1))/60
#[1] 301.25
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "PT5H1M15S"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string to get the pieces and then add them up.

```
TimeString = "PT5H1M15S"
HMS = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(TimeString, "[A-Z]+")))[2:4]
Minutes = 60*HMS[1] + HMS[2] + HMS[3]/60
Minutes
[1] 301.25
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.